# Notificação usando PHP e WebService no Android

Tags: java, android

Estou com um projeto em mente mas ainda não comecei a desenvolvê-lo na prática. A ideia é desenvolver um sistema Web PHP + MySql e uma aplicação Android utilizando WebServices. A minha dúvida é que se é possível gerar notificações no Android através do PHP?

**Por exemplo;**

Amanha é o dia do usuário X ir no dentista. No telefone do usuário X aparecerá uma notificação informando o compromisso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível sim, se você utilizar uma função na aplicação Android que é executada sempre em um tempo definido (a cada 1 minuto, por exemplo). Essa função deverá buscar se no WebService tem novas notificações para esse usuário.

## Editado

Achei um tutorial que mostra como consumir um `JSON` em Android: http://www.devmedia.com.br/consumindo-json-em-aplicacoes-android/27589. 
O que você deve fazer, é adicionar um método que vá buscar o WebService (eu sempre utilizo em REST por já ter conhecimento) sempre a cada x segundos/minutos. Na aplicação PHP, quando executado o método REST (caso tenha algo a enviar para a aplicação Android), disponibiliza as informações e, depois de executado pelo Android, você deve remover essas informações do WS (logicamente ou fisicamente), para que não haja duplicidade de informações enviadas

## Editado 2

Após configurado o arquivo AndroidManifest para que o usuário tenha acesso a internet e importado o *package* do `JSON`, cria-se o método (nesse exemplo, ele é executado a cada 5000 ms, ou seja, a cada 5 segundos):

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          new DownloadJsonAsyncTask()
              .execute("http://meusite.com.br.meujson.json");
      }
}, 0, 5000);
```

No WS `PHP`:

```
<?php

$objetosJson = [];
$objetosJson[] = array('Objeto' => array('id' => 1, 'nome' => 'João'));
$objetosJson[] = array('Objeto' => array('id' => 2, 'nome' => 'Maria'));
echo json_encode($objetosJson);die;
```

Comment: Julyano bom dia, você tem algum exemplo prático disso ?

Comment: Vou providenciar um exemplo, um momento.

Comment: Pode exemplificar com código aqui o que tem no link? Respostas que dependam de links não são encorajadas aqui, vai que num futuro esse link fique inacessivel?

Answer (score 2):

Eu utilizo o google GCM, onde voce pode enviar as notificacoes push para o aparelho do usuario.

Aqui tem o exemplo de como usar com o PHP https://github.com/mattg888/GCM-PHP-Server-Push-Message

E aqui um outro exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging

Comment: O problema do GCM é que é uma plataforma paga e esse projeto que tenho em mente, é um sisteminha básico para gerenciar o café da manha aqui da empresa.

Comment: Achei que seu app era pra testes e entender como implementar a notificacao. Embora o GCM tenha 60 dias gratis para testar, a sua utilização realmente é paga.

Comment: Queria aqui só ressaltar que o GCM foi descontinuado, favorecendo o FCM. Se não me engano, o FCM é mais acessível do que o GCM, acho que boa parte dele é gratuita (com limitações, tipo, 5 chamados por ano, mas uso gratuito)